# GWT simplegrid is not displayed without initwidget

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I have a problem with the simplegrid class: in my project I have a class that extends **Vertical Panel** in which I put a **simplegrid**. The problem is that if I don't call the method **initWidget** I cannot see the **simplegrid** (it loads data, but doesn't display).
I know that calling **initWidget** solves the problem because a few days ago my class extended **Composite** instead of **Vertical Panel** and everything worked fine.

Does anyone know why I have to call **initWidget** to make the simple grid to be displayed?

Comment: There is no any code. so can you add some code to show what you have done?

Answer (score 1):

The **Composite** is just a wrapper for another widget. For example, you could wrap a **VerticalPanel** and add two **Label** widgets to it, one as a header and the other underneath to display the associated data.

The **Composite** widget has to know which of these other widgets it is supposed to wrap, and you tell it with the `initWidget(Widget widget)` method. You MUST call this once and only once, or you will get an error.

Comment: Ok Janki, thanks for the answere, I've also read the documentation and found this answere, but I'd like to know how to create a class that extends a VerticalPanel and in witch I can put a SimpleGrid. Actually I cannot do that directly because if I don't call the method initWidget the SimpleGrid's data don't appear and in a VerticalPanel I do not have the initWidget method..

Comment: @Jaxer, I am able to render Grid in vertical panel without using initWidget in Gwt 2.4. Which version of GWT are you using? Provide a standalone case.